# Got this crash report from Crittercism. Can not find out what is the reason for the crash. Any hints will be helpful

Tags: ios6, ios7, crash, crash-reports

```
0   
libobjc.A.dylib 0x38e86b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   
SureSMSClient 0x000dc351 0x0009f000 + 250705
2   
SureSMSClient 0x000d5ce3 0x0009f000 + 224483
3   
UIKit 0x314d98d1 -[_UICompatibilityTextView keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:] + 197
4   
UIKit 0x3149cadf -[UIWebDocumentView keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:] + 131
5   
UIKit 0x3141bc3b -[UIKeyboardImpl callShouldInsertText:] + 199
6   
UIKit 0x3141b861 -[UIKeyboardImpl completeAcceptCandidateBeforeAddingInput:executionContext:] + 865
7   
UIKit 0x3141b4e9 __60-[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:withFlags:executionContext:]_block_invoke + 37
8   
UIKit 0x3129b317 -[UIKeyboardTaskExecutionContext returnExecutionToParent] + 247
9   
UIKit 0x31379931 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptCurrentCandidateIfSelectedWithExecutionContext:] + 233
10  
UIKit 0x3141b197 -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:withFlags:executionContext:] + 387
11  
UIKit 0x3141af1b -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyWithString:forKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 571
12  
UIKit 0x3141a961 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 1569
13  
UIKit 0x31419935 -[UIKeyboardImpl _handleKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 213
14  
UIKit 0x31418c4d -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar completeRetestForTouchUp:timestamp:interval:executionContext:] + 3261
15  
UIKit 0x31417dab -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:executionContext:] + 1471
16  
UIKit 0x31417747 __28-[UIKeyboardLayout touchUp:]_block_invoke + 223
17  
UIKit 0x31298a49 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 353
18  
UIKit 0x31414a57 -[UIKeyboardLayout touchUp:] + 239
19  
UIKit 0x314148df -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 323
20  
UIKit 0x312a2dd9 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 529
21  
UIKit 0x3129de65 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 833
22  
UIKit 0x3127379d -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 197
23  
UIKit 0x31271fa3 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7099
24  
CoreFoundation 0x2eac7183 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
25  
CoreFoundation 0x2eac6653 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 207
26  
CoreFoundation 0x2eac4e47 __CFRunLoopRun + 623
27  
CoreFoundation 0x2ea2fc27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
28  
CoreFoundation 0x2ea2fa0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
29  
GraphicsServices 0x3370e283 GSEventRunModal + 139
30  
UIKit 0x312d3049 UIApplicationMain + 1137
31  
SureSMSClient 0x000a016f 0x0009f000 + 4463
```

Answer (score 0):

`objc_msgSend` in a crash is frequently an indicator of a message being sent to a deallocated object.  Otherwise, it might be a message sent to the wrong type of object (bad cast or something).  It appears to be happening in a text view delegate's method.

If that doesn't narrow it down enough, try the `atos` utility from a terminal window.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and will reply if I can solve this crash. It was very helpful to me.